# setState is not changing value of boolean parameter

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a modal in React and have it working successfully elsewhere in my application. However, in the following code snippet, `this.state.display` is never being set to `false`. I can console log around it, see that the function is firing, but `this.state.display` is set to `true` after initialization throughout the entire lifecycle.

```
class AdvancedToDoModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      display: false,
      modalContent: this.fetchModalContent(props)
    }

    this.fetchModalContent = this.fetchModalContent.bind(this);

    this.numberInput = this.numberInput.bind(this);
    this.dateInput = this.dateInput.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
  }

  numberInput() {
    return (
      <div>Number Input</div>
    )
  }

  dateInput() {
    return (
      <div>Date Input</div>
    )
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({ display: true })
  }

  hideModal() {
    console.log('hide')
    this.setState({ display: false }, () => {
      console.log('display is always true: ', this.state)
    });
  }

  fetchModalContent(props) {
    var modalContent;

    if (props.inputType === 'number') {
      modalContent = this.numberInput();
    } else if (props.inputType === 'date') {
      modalContent = this.dateInput();
    } else {
      modalContent = null;
      console.log('Unknown inputType');
    }

    return modalContent;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.showModal} className={this.state.display} style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
        <Modal display={this.state.display} title={this.props.title} onClose={this.hideModal} >
          {this.state.modalContent}
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: As a note, make sure to call `super(props);` with the `props` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have one onClick handler on a parent element which sets the state when you click close button. Look at your render function

```
render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.showModal} className={this.state.display} style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
        <Modal display={this.state.display} title={this.props.title} onClose={this.hideModal} >
          {this.state.modalContent}
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Here at the root div you have onClick handler which calls showModal which sets the `display` state to true. Now when in modal you click on any close button that calls your `hideModal`, but after that, your parent div's `onClick` is also called which sets you state again to true. Therefore your `display` state always remain true. Remove this `onClick` handler and it will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that the `div` still technically surrounds the modal, even though the modal is displayed on top of everything else with `z-index` - that still doesn't change the structure of the HTML document, just the visual component! Much appreciated!